# Operator != is ambiguous for std::reverse_iterator c++

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading, std, reverse-iterator

I am working on a container that implements its own iterator, which I am using with std::reverse_iterator<> to get reverse iteration functionality. I can assign the reverse iterator to rend or rbegin, but when i try to access any of its functionality (such as != or ==) I get this:

```
1   IntelliSense: more than one operator "!=" matches these operands:
        function template "bool std::operator!=(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt1> &_Left, const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &_Right)"
        function template "bool avl::operator!=(const tree &left, const tree &right)"
        operand types are: std::reverse_iterator<avl::avl_iterator<avl::avltree<char, int, std::less<char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const char, int>>>>> != std::reverse_iterator<avl::avl_iterator<avl::avltree<char, int, std::less<char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const char, int>>>>>
```

My iterator operator overloads:

```
bool operator == ( const avl_iterator& rhs ) const { return ( _node == rhs._node); }
    bool operator != ( const avl_iterator& rhs ) const { return ( _node != rhs._node); }
```

and my implementation of reverse iterator

```
typedef typename avl_iterator< tree >                               iterator;
typedef typename const_avl_iterator< tree >                         const_iterator;
typedef typename std::reverse_iterator<iterator>                    reverse_iterator;
typedef typename std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>              const_reverse_iterator;
```

and the iterator typedefs:

```
    typedef typename tree::node                 node;
    typedef typename tree::node_ptr             node_ptr;
    typedef typename tree::value_type*          pointer;// for std reverse iterator
    typedef typename tree::value_type&          reference;
    typedef typename tree::const_node_ptr       const_node_ptr;
    typedef typename tree::utilities            utilities;
    typedef typename tree::value_type           value_type;
    typedef std::bidirectional_iterator_tag     iterator_category;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t                      difference_type;
```

How I'm using the operator

```
    avltree<char,int> myTree;
    myTree.insert(std::pair<char,int>('a',1));
    myTree.insert(std::pair<char,int>('b',2));
    myTree.insert(std::pair<char,int>('c',3));

    avltree<char,int>::reverse_iterator rit = myTree.rbegin();

    for(; rit != myTree.rend(); ++rit) //fails on this line
    {
    }
```

and the iterator class (const_iterator is the same thing but with a const value_type)

```
template <class tree>
class avl_iterator {
public:
    typedef typename tree::node                 node;
    typedef typename tree::node_ptr             node_ptr;
    typedef typename tree::value_type*          pointer;// for std reverse iterator
    typedef typename tree::value_type&          reference;
    typedef typename tree::const_node_ptr       const_node_ptr;
    typedef typename tree::utilities            utilities;
    typedef typename tree::value_type           value_type;
    typedef std::bidirectional_iterator_tag     iterator_category;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t                      difference_type;

private:
    friend class const_avl_iterator<tree>;
    node_ptr _node;
public:
    avl_iterator() : _node()  { }
    avl_iterator( const node_ptr node ) : _node ( node ) { }
    avl_iterator( const avl_iterator& iterator ) {
        (*this) = iterator;
    }
    ~avl_iterator() { _node = NULL; }

    avl_iterator& operator=(const avl_iterator& rhs) {
        _node = rhs._node;
        return (*this);
    }
    avl_iterator& operator=(const const_avl_iterator<tree>& rhs) {
        _node = rhs._node;
        return (*this);
    }

    bool operator == ( const avl_iterator& rhs ) const { return ( _node == rhs._node); }
    bool operator != ( const avl_iterator& rhs ) const { return ( _node != rhs._node); }

    avl_iterator& operator++()
    {
        _node = utilities::next_node( _node );
        return (*this);
    }
    avl_iterator operator ++( int ) {
        avl_iterator temp(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return(temp);
    }

    avl_iterator& operator -- () {
        _node = utilities::prev_node( _node );
        return (*this);
    }

    avl_iterator operator -- ( int ) {
        avl_iterator temp(*this);
        --(*this);
        return(temp);
    }

    value_type& operator * () const {
        assert( ! utilities::is_header( _node ) );
        return _node->_value;
    }

    value_type* operator -> () const {
        assert( ! utilities::is_header( _node ) );
        return &_node->_value;
    }
};
```

and the tree class:

```
template <
    class Key,
    class Type,
    class Traits = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<Key const, Type>>
    >
    class avltree {
    private:
        typedef avltree< Key, Type, Traits, Allocator>                      tree;
    public:
        typedef std::pair<const Key, Type>                                  value_type;
        typedef Allocator                                                   allocator_type;
        typedef typename allocator_type::size_type                          size_type;
        typedef typename allocator_type::reference                          reference;
        typedef Key                                                         key_type;
        typedef Type                                                        mapped_type;
        typedef Traits                                                      key_compare;
        typedef typename avl_node< tree >                                   node;
        typedef typename node::node_ptr                                     node_ptr;
        typedef typename node::const_node_ptr                               const_node_ptr;
        typedef typename avl_utilities< tree >                              utilities;
        typedef typename avl_iterator< tree >                               iterator;
        typedef typename const_avl_iterator< tree >                         const_iterator;
        typedef typename std::reverse_iterator<iterator>                    reverse_iterator;
        typedef typename std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator>              const_reverse_iterator;
    private:
        node_ptr _header;
        std::size_t _size;
        key_compare _comparer;
        allocator_type _alloc;
    public:
            //c'tors and d'tors
         //*******************************************************
        //Iterators
        //*******************************************************
        iterator                begin()         { return iterator( node::get_left( _header ) ); }
        const_iterator          begin() const   { return const_iterator( node::get_left( _header ) ); }
        const_iterator          cbegin() const  { return const_iterator( node::get_left( _header ) ); }
        iterator                end()           { return iterator( _header ); }
        const_iterator          end() const     { return const_iterator( _header ); }
        const_iterator          cend() const    { return const_iterator( _header ); }

        reverse_iterator        rbegin()        { return reverse_iterator( _header ); }
        const_reverse_iterator  rbegin() const  { return const_reverse_iterator( _header ); }
        const_reverse_iterator  crbegin() const { return const_reverse_iterator( _header ); }
        reverse_iterator        rend()          { return reverse_iterator( node::get_left( _header ) ); }
        const_reverse_iterator  rend() const    { return const_reverse_iterator( node::get_left( _header ) ); }
        const_reverse_iterator  crend() const   { return const_reverse_iterator( node::get_left( _header ) ); }
        bool operator==(const tree& right)
        {   
            if(_size != right.size())
            {
                return false;
            }

            const_iterator lhs = cbegin();
            const_iterator rhs = right.cbegin();
            while(lhs != cend() && rhs != right.cend() )
            {
                if(lhs->first != rhs->first || lhs->second != rhs->second)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                ++lhs;
                ++rhs;
            }
            return true;
        }
        bool operator!=(const tree& right)
        {
            return (!(*this == right));
        }
        bool operator<(const tree& right)
        {
            const_iterator lhs = cbegin();
            const_iterator rhs = right.cbegin();
            while(lhs != cend() && rhs != right.cend() )
            {
                if(lhs->first != rhs->first || lhs->second != rhs->second)
                {
                    if(lhs->first < rhs->first || lhs->second < rhs->second)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }                       
                }
                ++lhs;
                ++rhs;
            }
            return false;
        }
        bool operator>(const tree& right)
        {
            return ( right < *this );
        }
        bool operator<=(const tree& right)
        {
            return ( !(right < *this) );
        }
        bool operator>=(const tree& right)
        {
            return ( !(*this < right) );
        }
};
//*******************************************************
//Relation Operators
//*******************************************************
template<class tree>
bool operator==(const tree& left,const tree& right)
{   
    if(left.size() != right.size())
    {
        return false;
    }

    tree::const_iterator lhs = left.cbegin();
    tree::const_iterator rhs = right.cbegin();
    while(lhs != left.cend() && rhs != right.cend() )
    {
        if(lhs->first != rhs->first || lhs->second != rhs->second)
        {
            return false;
        }
        ++lhs;
        ++rhs;
    }
    return true;
}
template<class tree>
bool operator!=(const tree& left,const tree& right)
{
    return (!(left == right));
}
template<class tree>
bool operator<(const tree& left,const tree& right)
{
    tree::const_iterator lhs = left.cbegin();
    tree::const_iterator rhs = right.cbegin();
    while(lhs != left.cend() && rhs != right.cend() )
    {
        if(lhs->first != rhs->first || lhs->second != rhs->second)
        {
            if(lhs->first < rhs->first || lhs->second < rhs->second)
            {
                return true;
            }                       
        }
        ++lhs;
        ++rhs;
    }
    return false;
}
template<class tree>
bool operator>(const tree& left,const tree& right)
{
    return ( right < left );
}
template<class tree>
bool operator<=(const tree& left,const tree& right)
{
    return ( !(right < left) );
}
template<class tree>
bool operator>=(const tree& left,const tree& right)
{
    return ( !(left < right) );
}
}//end namespace avl
```

Comment: Does it compile? IntelliSense is NOT a compiler and shouldn't be trusted.

Comment: No, it gives the following error: Error 1 error C2593: 'operator !=' is ambiguous

Comment: Could you provide mini-example to check it, please?

Comment: @Riad - it's been added to the bottom of the post

Comment: Could you show the definition of your `avl_iterator` and `tree` classes?

Comment: @AndyProwl - added to the bottom of the post. I cut out some methods, as they don't relate to the problem

Comment: @SGrimminck: OK, could you show your `avl::operator !=`?

Comment: `tree` appears to be a template parameter, not a class.  But I would really like to see the declaration the compiler is referring to with: `function template "bool avl::operator!=(const tree &left, const tree &right)"`

Comment: @AndyProwl - I just finished posting that - I noticed I didn't get it when I posted the other ones sorry

Comment: @SGrimminck: you don't have a global `avl::operator !=`? Maybe for comparing trees?

Comment: template<class tree>
bool operator!=(const tree& left,const tree& right)
{
    return (!(left == right));
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On this line:

```
rit != myTree.rend()
```

You are comparing two objects of type:

```
avltree<char,int>::reverse_iterator
```

Which is in turn an alias for:

```
std::reverse_iterator<avl_iterator<char, int>::iterator>
```

The C++ Standard Library defines, in the `std::` namespace, a templated `operator !=` which is an exact match for comparing reverse iterators (see Paragraph 24.5 of the C++11 Standard):

```
template <class Iterator1, class Iterator2>
bool operator!=(
    const reverse_iterator<Iterator1>& x,
    const reverse_iterator<Iterator2>& y)
```

However, you also have this:

```
template<class tree> bool operator!=(const tree& left,const tree& right)
```

Since the template is unconstrained (even though the template parameter is named `tree`, this doesn't mean the template will only accept trees), this is also an exact match, but the templated `operator !=` for reverse iterators is still more specialized.

Therefore, the call should **not** be ambiguous. I think this is a compiler bug.

---

To fix the issue, make sure your inequality operator for trees only accept trees, which is anyway a good idea (you really don't want your operator to compare *anything* after all):

```
template<class T> bool operator!=(const avltree<T>& left,const avltree<T>& right)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `operator !=` tries to compare any time, including `reverse_iterator`s, you may try use

```
template<class T> bool operator!= (const avltree<T>& left,const avltree<T>& right) {     
    return (!(left == right)); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a broken compiler.

```
template<typename Iter>
bool std::operator!=(const std::reverse_iterator<Iter>&,
                     const std::reverse_iterator<Iter>&);
```

is "more specialized than"

```
template<class tree>
bool avl::operator!=(const tree&, const tree&);
```

so the expression `rit != myTree.rend()` should not be ambiguous.

Still, declaring something that can apply `!=` to *any* two objects of the same type is a dangerous idea.

Answer (score -1):

You try to compare a const_reverse_iterator to a reverse_iterator, the call to rend() will always use the non-const overload if available. A fix for this should be obvious. The same problem existed with some early std::set implementations, if I remember correctly.

Anyhow, there's a good approach that would work around this issue while being IMHO even more elegant:

```
for(container::iterator it=c.begin(), end=c.end(); it!=end; ++it)
    ...
```

In other words, always use a pair of iterators that are declared in the for-loop's header. using C++11's "auto", this becomes even shorter. While the single call to end() is not faster with any halfway-modern compiler, I personally find it a tiny bit clearer.

Comment: `rbegin()`, `rend()` are both `reverse_iterators`

Comment: You're missing the point. If taken verbatim, that statement of yours is even wrong, because they are overloaded. One overload of each `begin()` and `end()` returns a `const_reverse_iterator` and the other returns a `reverse_iterator`. While conversion from non-const to const works obviously, this doesn't guarantee that comparisons between the two work.